# VPN - "ADD" button is not active!

Tags: networking, 12.10, lubuntu

when i open Network Connections window, everything is ok but in the VPN tab. nothing is active there, even the ADD button.
i need to make a pptp connection, but i have no idea how.

here's the pictures of Network Connections tabs:
http://www.use.com/25186c67336ee527642b

days ago i was running Lubuntu 11.10 and there was no problem, but in 12.10 i found this problem.

Comment: I solved my problem by analyzing the import difference between Windows and Linux, it seems that in linux in mine I was not going up the gateway of the routes, after manually placing the same enabled the button to add the vpn and connect successfully.
Hope this helps. ABC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step By Step Instructions](https://www.versavpn.com/ubuntu-linux-configuring-running-pptp/)

But as you don't have the add button, there are a few things to check first.

1. Make sure you have a vpn client installed `sudo apt-get install pptp-linux` should do it
2. Make sure the 'network manager' modules are installed `sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome`
3. Make sure your authorized to edit network connections. Best way to answer this is can you sudo.

Comment: i really dont know how to THANK YOU. the second way solved the problem. thank you man :))))))

Comment: Unfortunately your two suggestions did not work. And the link to the Step-by-spte instructions is stale.

Comment: well it was written 10 years ago, it might be out of date, but Ask Ubuntu isn't really a forum. You might have better luck on the Ubuntu Forums.