# Lubuntu 12.10 The add button still not active

Tags: 12.10, wireless, vpn, connection

I cant seem to add VPN from my network connections.

This [similar post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218798/vpn-add-button-is-not-active) doesn't  help me since I can't connect to the Internet with my Netbook to fetch the installation. Any ideas on how to fix this without the help of Internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fix.. If you want to install it manually download  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?ke...-kernel-source for bcmwl-kernel-source
and every packages required to install bcmwl-kernel-source  :)
then run the debian file

Sorry if it got off topic :(