# VPN PPTP in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, vpn, pptp

Can anybody tell me how to make a PPTP in Lubuntu?

When I try to add VPN connection there isn't any filed there I have to choose PPTP

Comment: Do you have `network-manager-pptp` installed? Run `dpkg -l | grep network-manager-pptp` to check, and if not, try installing the package.

Answer (score 6):

there are a few things to check first.

1. Make sure you have a vpn client installed `sudo apt-get install pptp-linux` should do it
2. Make sure the 'network manager' modules are installed `sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome`
3. Make sure your authorized to edit network connections. Best way to answer this is can you sudo.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218798/vpn-add-button-is-not-active)

Comment: To restart I had to execute: "sudo systemctl restart network-manager"